# Javascript: False if statement always evaluates as true

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am writing a simple console based rock paper scissors game as an exercise. However, the following condition always evaluates to true.

```
if (playerselection === computerselection) {
        console.log('Draw!');
```

I have introduced several console.log commands as well as breakpoints to identify whether there's an issue with scope, or alteration in parameters; this does not seem to be the case. playerselection could be 'Rock', while computerselection could be 'Scissors' (both verified during debugging) and yet the condition is treated as true and the console outputs "Draw!).
The entire code is seen below:

```
array = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];

computerPlay();
userPlay();
evaluation();


function computerPlay() {
    computerselection = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

function userPlay() {
    playerselection = prompt('Choose: Rock, Paper or Scissors', 'Choose it! NOW!!');
}


function evaluation(playerselection, computerselection) {
    if (playerselection === computerselection) {
        console.log('Draw!');

    } else if (
    (playerselection == "rock" && computerselection == "scissors") ||          //All possible victories
    (playerselection == "paper" && computerselection == "rock") || 
    (playerselection == "scissors" && computerselection == "paper")) {
        console.log("You win!");

    } else {
        console.log("You lose)");
    }
}
```

What is the causing the first if condition to evaluate as true every time, even if console.log(playerselection === computerselection) evaluates as false during debugging?

Comment: of course, you never hand over a value, hence both values are `undefined` and equal.

Comment: undefined === undefined is always true

Comment: `evaluation();` You need to pass the values as parameters.

Comment: `evaluation` takes two parameters. They shadow the global variables. Since you don't pass any arguments, both are `undefined`.

Comment: Here `evaluation();` you never pass parameters. Vars in functions are scoped "locally" to the function unless they are declared globally elsewhere. Hence all the above comments. Beyond that and even after fixing it, you are going to have unexpected results because you declare the computer's answer as an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints.

In

```
function evaluation(playerselection, computerselection) {
```

you have a declaration of two (locale) variables and you use them for the comparison.

Later, you call the function

```
evaluation()
```

without some parameters and Javascript takes a default value of `undefined`, like for all other declarated variables without value.

Here the code with some changes:

- declaration of any variable in advance,
- return the value of the array of the input,
- use both value directly in `evaluation`,
- exit early to prevent nested `if` ... `else` structures,
- prevent using unnecessary parentheses, have a look to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), if in doubt.

The data in `array` should be in lowercase as the input.

```js
function computerPlay() {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

function userPlay() {
    return (prompt('Choose: rock, paper or scissors') || '').toLowerCase();
}

function evaluation(playerselection, computerselection) {
    if (playerselection === computerselection) {
        console.log('Draw!');
        return;
    } 
    if (
        playerselection === "rock" && computerselection === "scissors" ||
        playerselection === "paper" && computerselection === "rock" ||
        playerselection === "scissors" && computerselection === "paper"
    ) {
        console.log("You win!");
        return;
    }
    console.log("You lose");
}

const
    array = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];

evaluation(userPlay(), computerPlay());
```

Comment: The code provided does not seem to evaluate any true conditions for winning as true. For example: playerselection = scissors, computerselection = paper, yet the console outputs "you lose". 

During debugging the third if statement should've evaluated as true, but it instead evaluated as false and printed a loss.

Comment: @ChristosBinos, `array` should havelower case letters as well, because any comparison with lower case input would be `false`. please see edit.

Comment: I found it worked best to ensure that the string obtained from the user prompt is converted to lowercase via .toLowerCase. This ensures that "roCK" or any other unintentional permutation does not hinder program. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here both the variables are not in global scope and hence not accessible inside evaluate() function. This is the reason, due to which both are `undefined` inside evaluate() and satisfying if condition every time.

Try to define both the variables in global scope like below and remove parameters from evaluate() function declaration.

```
let computerselection = "";
let playerselection = "";
function evaluation() {
   //code stuff
}
```